# Unable to access Internet on Kali Linux light

Tags: kali-linux

Good day to you guys here.
I downloaded a version of Kali Linux light from the official Kali Linux site, and I run the program live from my flash drive. 
I connected the the system to my Android phone hotspot.
Everything other things seems to work well until I tried to install some app from the internet.
The error I always get is: "Temporary failure in name resolution"
I've googled this error message over and over again, but I'm still unable to access the net.
Is "Kali Linux light" this light because it can't be connected to the internet?

UPDATE:
After a lot of searches here and there, I later came across an article that confirmed that my version of NetworkManager is slightly faulty. Now, I've switched to connman, and everything has been going well

Comment: I think you'll get an answer to "Is "Kali Linux light" this light because it can't be connected to the internet?" if you read [What's the difference between Kali Linux Large, Light and normal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538797/whats-the-difference-between-kali-linux-large-light-and-normal).

Answer (score -1):

Please check `/etc/resolv.conf` the file might be some entry not resolving or check `/etc/hosts` file and add the correct Hostname.

Thanks

Comment: root@kali: ~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1        localhost Kali
::1                    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0            ip6-localnet
ff00::0             ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1             ip6-allnodes
ff02::2             ip6-allrouters


root@kali: ~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.43.1

Comment: There is no information in this answer at all. If you want to request more information from the user in the question, do that in a comment to the question rather than in an answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda how could that user comment if he hasn't enough reputation?

Comment: @mosvy By first getting more reputation through answering questions properly.

Comment: @Kusalananda Could you help me, please? I'll provide any information you need.

Comment: @dammy999 I can not. I'm not running Linux. Your issue is with the name server that you have configured or decided to use, or that have been assigned to you. I can't say more than that really as I can't replicate your setup.

Comment: @Kusalananda   I guess it isn't my name server config, but a fault in the version of NetworkManager that I have. Now I'm able to connect successfully using connman with the same name server configurations that wasn't successful while using NetworkManager.